# HTK HSGen [+8250] error?

Tags: signal-processing, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, htk

I want to use the HTK toolbox for digit recognition. so I downloaded it and read the instruction about how to use it! But when I want to use the **`HSGen`** I encounter with this error:

```
ERROR [+8250] ReadLattice: 23 Arcs unseen and 15 Nodes unseen
ERROR [+3410] GenSentences: ReadLattice failed
FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HSGen
```

So the steps I did is as follows:

make a grammer, my file content is exactly as it is stored in a file named **gram**:

```
    $digit = ONE|TWO|THREE|FOUR|FIVE|SIX|SEVEN|EIGHT|NINE|ZERO;

    (SENT-START ($digit) SENT-END)
```

Using `HParse` command to make a network for this grammar, its content is(stored in a file named **wdnet**) :

`I=0    W=!NULL

    I=1    W=!NULL

    I=10   W=SEVEN

    I=11   W=EIGHT

    I=12   W=NINE

    I=13   W=ZERO

    I=14   W=SENT-END

    I=2    W=SENT-START

    I=3    W=ONE

    I=4    W=!NULL

    I=5    W=TWO

    I=6    W=THREE

    I=7    W=FOUR

    I=8    W=FIVE

    I=9    W=SIX

    J=0     S=14   E=1

    J=1     S=0    E=2

    J=10    S=11   E=4

    J=11    S=12   E=4

    J=12    S=13   E=4

    J=13    S=2    E=5

    J=14    S=2    E=6

    J=15    S=2    E=7

    J=16    S=2    E=8

    J=17    S=2    E=9

    J=18    S=2    E=10

    J=19    S=2    E=11

    J=2     S=2    E=3

    J=20    S=2    E=12

    J=21    S=2    E=13

    J=22    S=4    E=14

    J=3     S=3    E=4

    J=4     S=5    E=4

    J=5     S=6    E=4

    J=6     S=7    E=4

    J=7     S=8    E=4

    J=8     S=9    E=4

    J=9     S=10   E=4

    N=15   L=23

    VERSION=1.0`

I have a *word list* file named as **wlist2**, its content is:

```
    EIGHT
    FIVE
    FOUR
    NINE
    ONE
    SENT-END
    SENT-START
    SEVEN
    SIX
    THREE
    TWO
    ZERO
```

I use the **`HDMan`** command to build the dictionary file:

```
    HDMan -m -w wlist2 -n monophones -l dlog2 dict2 mbeep2
```

which *mbeep2* is my dictionary that contains the pronounciations for each word in my *wlist2*. the ouput file is created in the file named **dict2**.

When using **HSGen** with this command:

```
    HSGen -l -n 200 wdnet dict2 > testprompets
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR [+8250] ReadLattice: 23 Arcs unseen and 15 Nodes unseen
ERROR [+3410] GenSentences: ReadLattice failed
FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HSGen
```

I search the error number but coudln't find a related solution! Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm running htk on windows 7.

Comment: You probably somehow corrupted the lattice with invisible symbols by opening it in a text editor or something like that. You need to share the files in archive through file sharing service like dropbox, not paste them in a question.

Comment: No I did not open it! after I got the error I opened the file. the pasting was for reader convenience

Comment: Instead of trying to deny it's better to share the files.

Comment: OK! :) here you are: http://goo.gl/NPWh31 , all files included!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened with your wdnet file, but it somehow has lines in reverse order and it also misses few lines. You probably need to repeat the HParse command:

```
 HParse gram wdnet
```

The result should look like this:

```
VERSION=1.0
N=15   L=23   
I=0    W=!NULL               
I=1    W=!NULL               
I=2    W=SENT-START          
I=3    W=ONE                 
I=4    W=!NULL               
I=5    W=TWO                 
I=6    W=THREE               
I=7    W=FOUR                
I=8    W=FIVE                
I=9    W=SIX                 
I=10   W=SEVEN               
I=11   W=EIGHT               
I=12   W=NINE                
I=13   W=ZERO                
I=14   W=SENT-END            
J=0     S=14   E=1    
J=1     S=0    E=2    
J=2     S=2    E=3    
J=3     S=3    E=4    
J=4     S=5    E=4    
J=5     S=6    E=4    
J=6     S=7    E=4    
J=7     S=8    E=4    
J=8     S=9    E=4    
J=9     S=10   E=4    
J=10    S=11   E=4    
J=11    S=12   E=4    
J=12    S=13   E=4    
J=13    S=2    E=5    
J=14    S=2    E=6    
J=15    S=2    E=7    
J=16    S=2    E=8    
J=17    S=2    E=9    
J=18    S=2    E=10   
J=19    S=2    E=11   
J=20    S=2    E=12   
J=21    S=2    E=13   
J=22    S=4    E=14
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable I and J in your wdnet should put in order